# Drupal site on a free server

Tags: drupal, server

Does anyone know of any free servers that do a reasonable job of hosting a simple Drupal site? I know of Heliohost but after trying it I found it to be very slow (you get what you pay for clearly), but based on your experience are there any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

You have to choose either free or Drupal, as it is Ram-greedy beast, you cannot feed it with free social sandwiches.
However, you can try cheap hosting plans, few years ago I used to host about 20 small Drupal sites on a $50/year account.